# Vuejs - Llamar un componente importado de forma dinamica

Tags: vuejs

Tengo un componente con estructura de `<modal>` importado en `main.js` para hacer uso de forma global.

Este componente tiene varios usos, es decir... puede utilizarse para diferentes casos de despliegue de información.

Este modal tengo que estarlo incluyendo en cada template donde debe utilizarse

```
<template> 
  <modal /> //myModal
  ...<div> etc.
</template>
```

Hay alguna forma de llamar a este modal sin necesidad de estarlo incluyendo en cada template, es decir mediante un `botón` o un `metodo`.

```
methods:{
   callModal(){
      //Llamar al modal directamente desde código sin necesidad de importarlo al template parent
    }
}
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo y cómo pasar las propiedades de forma dinamica?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes dejar la alerta en tu componente principal y usar $emit para llamar al codigo que lo mostrara u ocultara... y que al tocar cierto boton, emitas un evento...

https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

componente de alerta en root:

```
<alerta ... @mostrarAlerta="metodoalerta" />
```

metodo que mostrara alerta en methods del root...

```
methods: {
  metodoalerta(mensaje) {
    // codigo que muestra alerta... se puede usar mensaje o que no tenga params...
  }
}
```

podras llamarlo desde cualquier parte del codigo... (mensaje opcional)

```
this.$emit('mostraralerta', mensaje);
```

te dejo algunos ejemplos de varias maneras de implementar una llamada entre componentes (en ingles):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035310/open-a-vuetify-dialog-from-a-component-template-in-vuejs

*nota: @ es un alias de v-on:, por lo que es lo mismo poner v-on:mostraralerta que @mostrarAlerta*